# Records are inserting less in the database when we increase the thread group count from 100 to 200 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Initially i have ran a load test with 100 users for 10 minutes and 1000 records got inserted in the database for the below scenarios.

1. Employee Creation -- Test script design took 1 minute
2. Employee Update -- Test script design took 2 minutes

And then I ran the same load test with 200 users for 10 minutes and 1100 records got inserted without any error logs or deadlocks. 
**My question is when we increase/double the thread group count from 100 to 200, Records insertion also should be double or approximately double. then why is it not happening? Same case with the number requests/samples.**

Comment: Application response time is the factor that affects this. If application is not scalable enough to handle that much requests, then it may demonstrate the behaviour specified by you

Comment: Thank You Nans... But the CPU & RAM usage is not more than 40% through out the load run. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: CPU and RAM usage increase need not happen for a performance bottleneck. You may check how many threads your application is using in both scenarios. Is it same or different? Also, any db bottlenecks observed? How many connections does your application has with the db? Is it scalable? All these contributes to application performance

Answer (score 0):

You reached a maximum in your test [throughput](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/05/performance-testing-what-is-throughput/) at about 110 records per min. In other words, you have a bottleneck on client or server, which doesn't allow 200 users to process request concurrently and/or within the same amount of time (either some users wait until they can start processing a request, or each request takes longer, so total number of requests is lower).

Some bottlenecks can be resolved by you (if they are related to script, JMeter configuration or JMeter machine), others have to be resolved on server side (by whoever has access to it), and some cannot be resolved at all (they are true bottlenecks of your app).

Without knowing your application, it's hard to suggest anything beyond general "checklist" items:

1. Verify JMeter script and check if it has any places where it may wait, take a long time, and so on. For example if your ramp-up period is too high, it may be that "first" user will finish execution, before "last" user even started it. Scriptable samplers, pre- and post-processors may cause delays as well.
2. Make sure JMeter is configured properly to handle 200 concurrent threads. For example if JMeter heap is set too low, it could be that JMeter is very slow, as it constantly needs to run GC. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286750/jmeter-outofmemoryerror) question for how to look at and configure memory (it discusses out of memory error, but even without that error inadequate memory can cause slowness)
3. Make sure JMeter machine is configured correctly to allow creation of 200+ HTTP connections concurrently. A common issue on both Windows and Linux machine is that people assume that they can have 65535 connections (as maximal number of ports), but in reality, both Windows and Linux limit number of ports they allow by default to be used. Also after the use port may remain in TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT state for several minutes, which makes it unusable. As a result, running out of ports is quite common. Here's how to monitor and resolve this issue on [Windows](https://community.ipswitch.com/s/article/Avoiding-TCP-IP-Port-Exhaustion) and [Linux](http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/).
4. Check JMeter machine performance as a whole: does it have enough CPU, memory; is it swapping memory, etc.
5. If none of the above is a problem, you need to look at how requests arrive to the server. If client is capable of sending 200 concurrent requests (which you should have established in previous steps), but server receives them at slower rate, then maybe something in the network slows things down. For example something like slow DNS resolution or slow routing between JMeter and server can cause issues.
6. Also Item #3 on the client is also applicable to the server.
7. If requests do arrive to the server at the same speed as they are sent from the client, then probably their processing by the server slows down as number of parallel requests goes up. This is where you are on dev and devOP territory, and probably need to work with them to identify bottlenecks on server side. It could be configuration of the web or application server, application itself, ... anything on app way pretty much.

Performance testing is 10% execution, and 90% analysis and identification of bottlenecks, so here you go.