# JMeter - OutOfMemoryError How to change heap size in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Recently I run the load test of 5k users for 30 minutes using concurrency thread group. When I want to read file in the Graph Report listener, this out of memory error prompted on the cmd:

[image]

I tried to modify the heap size to 6GB in notepad++ (my laptop spec: 16GB DDR4, 512GB SSD, i5 7th gen, available ram 10GB):

[image]

But in the jmeter cmd screen, it does not shows the changes i made just now. how to exactly change the heap size? I tried to follow the steps already using notepad++ but seems not working for me. Anything that I missed out here? I followed the steps from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure by Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

[image]

Comment: This line is a comment (start with `rem`) you need to write in a different line as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286750/jmeter-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 2):

1. The easiest is setting `HEAP` [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) like:

   ```
    set HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && jmeter -n -t test.jmx
   ```
2. In order  to make the change permanent modify the [line # 151 of jmeter.bat startup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L151)
3. Don't pay attention to the console message when you start JMeter in GUI mode, it's [hard-coded](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L367) and doesn't pick up any changes
4. If you're following recommendation to increase the heap why don't you follow the [recommendation to run the test in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)?

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: I just want to increase the heap to avoid the out of memory error. I got the error when i tried to read file in the jmeter listener (the result file which has been executed in non-gui mode)

Answer (score 0):

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx3g"

jmeter -t jmxfile.jmx
```

This will run jmeter with 3GB Max heap size.

Answer (score -1):

`set HEAP` is only for windows.
For Linux the .sh suggest to use `JVM_ARGS`

Here what I did on Linux (used the % feature of Java)

```bash
###set heap
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-XX:MinRAMPercentage=40.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90.0 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

the jmeter log will tell how much memory it has:

`2024-01-22 18:49:54,539 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =6765412352`