# Calculate Heap Size

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a test where I have 500 users ramping up in 180 seconds with a payload of size 4MB. I am running into OutOfMemoryError.

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:/Users/ajay/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.4/performancetests/PerformanceTest_Insert_500_4mb_180.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Wed Jul 27 17:25:10 EDT 2022 (1658957110058)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
summary +     15 in 00:00:20 =    0.8/s Avg: 12865 Min:  8125 Max: 16208 Err:     1 (6.67%) Active: 41 Started: 55 Finished: 14
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid14800.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [885999816 bytes in 2.700 secs]
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-101,5,main]. See log file for details.
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286750/jmeter-outofmemoryerror) and few other googled results so I have below config:

```
if not defined HEAP (
    rem See the unix startup file for the rationale of the following parameters,
    rem including some tuning recommendations
    set HEAP=-Xms2g -Xmx6g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
)
```

Question: How do I calculate how much heap size I would need for my test's specifications so that I can avoid above OOM error?

Answer (score 1):

How about the size of the response? The number of [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)? Are there any [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) enabled?

There is no formula to exactly calculate heap usage because there are too many unknown factors, what you can do is to measure heap usage for 1 user, 50 users, 100 users [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or similar tool and see how does it change and if you extrapolate it to 500 you should get the required value.

Also the choice should not be "sufficient", it should be ["optimal"](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Java.html#Java-Garbage_Collection-Optimal_Heap_Size)

> "If the occupancy of the Java heap is too high, garbage collection occurs frequently. If the occupancy is low, garbage collection is infrequent but lasts longer... Try to keep the memory occupancy of the Java heap between 40% and 70% of the Java heap size... The highest point of occupancy of the Java heap is preferably not above 70% of the maximum heap size, and the average occupancy is between 40% and 70% occupancy. If the occupancy goes over 70%, resize the Java heap."

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)

Comment: This is helpful Dmitri. I will go thru them and will try to tweak my setup. And will come back again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't need you to come back, your commend neither makes sense nor adds any value